# Prove or disprove : if $a_n$ has a limit and $b_n$ doesn't have a limit then $a_n + b_n$ doesn't have a limit

Tags: limits, infinity

I think it's wrong but I couldn't find an example that disproves this. If this is true I need to prove it and if it's wrong I have to give an example to disprove it.

Comment: It’s true. Suppose that $\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n+b_n)=c$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=a$; what can you say about $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n$?

Comment: Use algebra of limits.

Answer (score 3):

Assume it's true, then

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(a_n+b_n\right)-\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$$

and then...

Answer (score 0):

Take $a_n=n$ and $b_n=(-1)^n$.
You can choose for $b_n$ any bounded sequence that doesn't converge, and $a_n$ as a diverging sequence.

Comment: but in this case you used algebra for limits for the limit of n which is infinity so can I consider this a disproving example because you cant use infinity in a law of limits algebra then you use it with the thought that this is a real number

Comment: You don't really have to use algebra of limits, if you don't want: let's call $c_n=a_n+b_n$, then $c_n=n+(-1)^n$. You can easily see that for every real number $M$ you can find $n^*\in\mathbb N$ such that $c_n>M$ for every $n>n^*$, and this is the very definition of a diverging sequence. No algebra of limits here.